# Group two arrays based off an if statement?

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

Very green to programming.

I have two arrays, one with numbers and one with text.

```
var time = [20,40,60,30,36];
var name = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];
```

What I want to do is something like:

If name == jon take all corresponding numbers(time) and group them. So it would take name[0] and time[0] and group it as well as jon[2] and time [2] and put it in the same group and so on and so forth. So I assume I would need to create new arrays but I'm not sure how to make the if statement without actually specifying the place in the array.

Comment: Start with `var people = {};` and loop through `name`. You can reference `people[name[i]]` and `time[i]` and add them together (creating it if it doesn't exist yet). By the end you should get `people = {jon:110, tim:40, andy:36};`

Comment: are you saying you want to do this dynamically for all distinct names that are the same, or you want to do this only for specific names you know beforehand?

Comment: @WookieCoder My if statement would be if name == "Jon" -> Group 1 -> Else -> Group 2

Comment: please don't use `name` as variable, because its a property of window and contains the [window name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name).

Comment: please add an example of the wanted result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for an array as result set, you could use a hash table for the indices of the result set.

```js
var time = [20, 40, 60, 30, 36],
    names = ["jon", "tim", "jon", "jon", "andy"],
    groups = {},
    result = [];
    
names.forEach(function (n, i) {
    if (!(n in groups)) {
        groups[n] = result.push([n, 0]) - 1;
    }
    result[groups[n]][1] += time[i];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over your names and use the same index to get the times. Put them in to a new object, setting the starting value of 0 if that name hasn't yet been used.

```js
var arr_time = [20,40,60,30,36];
var arr_name = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];

var rst = {};

arr_name.forEach(function( person, index ){
 rst[ person] = rst[ person] || 0;
    rst[ person] += arr_time[ index ];
});

console.log( rst );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group the items using Array#reduce.

**If you want the sums:**

```js
var time = [20,40,60,30,36];
var names = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];

var result = names.reduce(function(o, name, i) {  
  o[name] = (o[name] || 0) + time[i];
  
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

**If you want to group them in arrays:**

```js
var time = [20,40,60,30,36];
var names = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];

var result = names.reduce(function(o, n, i) {  
  o[n] = o[n] || [];
  
  o[n].push(time[i]);
  
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reach your desired result with `Array#reduce`.

```js
let time = [20, 40, 60, 30, 36];
let array = ["jon", "tim", "jon", "jon", "andy"];

const check = (name, arr) => {
  return { [name]: arr.reduce((s, a, i) => {
    a == name ? s.push(time[i]) : null;
    return s;
  }, [])};
}

console.log(check('jon', array));
console.log(check('tim', array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var time = [20,40,60,30,36];
   var names = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];
   var final = names.reduce(function(a, b, i) { 
                if(!(a.hasOwnProperty(b))) {
                     a[b] = 0;
                }
                 a[b] = a[b] + time[i];
                 return a;
              }, {});
```

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) check how reduce works it helps you to understand in better way.

Hope it helps you !

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using for loop. For each index in the `names` array, I am checking if the `result` object has that name. If it has that `name` I am adding the time corresponding to that index, otherwise I am adding that `name` to that `result` object and adding `time`.

```js
const times = [20,40,60,30,36];
const names = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];

var result = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < names.length ; ++i){
  let name = names[i];
  let time = times[i];
  if(result[name] !== undefined){
    result[name].push(time);
  } else {
    result[name] = [time];
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here is a solution using array `reduce`.

```js
var times = [20,40,60,30,36];
var names = ["jon","tim","jon","jon","andy"];

var result = names.reduce((obj, name, index) => {
   obj[name] = obj[name] || [];
   obj[name].push(times[index]);
   return obj;
},{});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```